# from greyscale to RGB

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am very new to photoshop. Absolutely I know nothing. I am following one tutorial to learn coloring.

I dnt understand two things-

1-  why did he  color everythng in greyscale first? Is this the same greyscale I found in Image mode? he activated that imagemode in greyscale and drew allathose shapes? or he just used 50 shades of grey? lol. I mean different grey colors he picked randomly from color?

2- what is the purpose of this greyscale coloring first?

3- When he used main color did he change the grey colors into the RGB? I mean from that image mode, now he changed greysclae into RGB and then start coloring?

please guide me. Thank you.

I tried many times to upload the GIF, but noway this site let me up bcz the file size is too big. even if its 4 mb

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you include a link to the tutorial? I can't decipher why the author intended to work in black and white and then color.

Comment: Best thing would be to ask the person who did this why they did what they did.

Comment: Hi. It's very difficult to unpick other people's tutorials. Different people have different methods of working, so you would really have to ask the creator of the tutorial why they did that.   A guess might be that they were using it for creating masks, but that's mere conjecture.

Comment: @BillyKerr you are absolutely right. I have seen masks attached with each layer. you are brilliant.

Comment: @AndrewH here you go ,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTaBR4kHsrM&t=32s

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I wish i could, he is no longer making tutorials

Comment: @AndrewH kindly let me know if you cud  decipher it.

Comment: Typically, by coloring grayscale allows you to concentrate on shading, and making the image easy to read.

Comment: @joojaa Thank you. I didnt knwo that